# MS EXCEL Coomand Button Colour change According to textbox value

Tags: vba, excel

I have named Command Buttons in userforms as"cb1", "cb2", "cb3"...
I want to change their colour according to the values entered in textbox i.e cb1 changes colour for value=1 and so on. Please help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Cb1.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'this will set backcolor to red
```

see [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251682(v=office.15).aspx) for RGB function values to get other colors